# Как поправить скрипт?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт вызова модального окна на javascript.По какой-то причине окно не появляется. Пишу так:

`<div id=checkPass>checkPass();</div>`

````
```function checkPass(){
  let pass = prompt('Введите пароль');
  let truePass='12345';
  let attempts=0;
  while (true){
    if(pass!==truePass){
      alert (`Неправильно`);
      attempts++;
    } else{
        break;
        alert(`Пароль верный. Вы угадали за .$.{attempts}.попыток`);
    }
  }
}```
````

Что ещё нужно дописать или исправить, чтобы этот код работал?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В представленном коде **НЕТ** вызова модального окна

Comment: А если назвать функцию также, как айдишник в html - то это действо **не вызывает функцию**.... и не должно

Comment: *"По какой-то причине окно не появляется"* --- потому что в коде нигде нет вызова

Comment: Добавил вызов функции. Результат остался тем же.

Comment: Не добавили, никакого вызова всё ещё нет